# "Add to homescreen" local web app fail on "location.href" (iPad 3)

Tags: ios, angularjs, html, mobile-safari, cache-manifest

I currently have a local web app that I created using the "add to homescreen" method on the iOS (cache.manifest). For some background, This is a quiz-type app that allows you to restart at the end. It is built in AngularJS, so all I have to do to "restart" the app is re-route by calling `location.href = '/app';` in JavaScript.

I have been testing this on many different iOS versions and iPad hardware versions, and everything seems to work fine except on iOS 7.1.2 on an iPad 3 (iOS 7.1.2 on iPad 4 is fine).

It seems to cache fine on the initial load, however when I restart the app (again - `location.href = '/app';`) it seems to fail and give the following error:

> "App-Name" could not be opened because it is not connected to the Internet.

I have done a lot of research and implemented almost all of the advice given on each successfully answered question regarding this error.

My cache.manifest:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

bower_components/angular/angular.min.js
bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js
bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js
bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js
bower_components/animate.css/animate.min.css
bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.min.js
bower_components/fastclick/fastclick.min.js
bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js
images/sfr1.png
images/sfr2.png
images/sfr3.png
images/sfr4.png
images/welcome.png
scripts/app.js
scripts/controllers/about.js
scripts/controllers/age.js
scripts/controllers/cct.js
scripts/controllers/challenge.js
scripts/controllers/finish.js
scripts/controllers/gen.js
scripts/controllers/iop.js
scripts/controllers/main.js
scripts/controllers/prr.js
scripts/controllers/ra.js
scripts/controllers/sfr.js
scripts/controllers/type.js
scripts/directives/pflash.js
scripts/directives/pnav.js
scripts/directives/pprofile.js
scripts/services/pservice.js
styles/main.css
styles/fonts/AvenirLTStd-Book.otf
styles/fonts/AvenirLTStd-Light.otf
styles/fonts/AvenirLTStd-Roman.otf
styles/fonts/danielbd.ttf
views/about.html
views/age.html
views/cct.html
views/challenge.html
views/finish.html
views/gen.html
views/iop.html
views/main.html
views/pnav.html
views/pp.html
views/prr.html
views/ra.html
views/sfr.html
views/type.html
index.html
```

This was also added to my .htaccess:

```
AddType text/cache-manifest appcache manifest
```

My assumption is that the iPad 3 has too many hardware limitations and cannot store as much cache within its local apps, causing it to fail. However, I wanted to take to StackOverflow to see if anyone else as other suggestions before I chock it up to something of that nature.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing you tried clearing the cache and then trying it again?

Comment: @WayneEllery yes, sir.